# Chatting using Bash Shell?

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, chat

The origins of the questions trace back to Mr. Robot series, where I noticed that people join "group" or "parties" chat through Bash Shell to communicate with other people or group. Then I got interested and started to search online for it and found answers for it, but only for LAN chats, not globally. I guess you have to have a server running so people can connect to it and chat through that or something similar to that. Can anyone please help me figure out how it works and how I can replicate it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many IRC clients that work CLI only.  One popular example is [irssi](https://irssi.org/).  You can use it to connect to your favorite IRC networks.  Using something like [BitlBee](https://www.bitlbee.org/) you can connect an IRC client to aim/jabber/and other IM networks.

Comment: Considering it's Mr. Robot. It's very, very likely IRC

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm not even near to your level to completely understand what you said, but I'll dig deep into it. Thank you!